# fontconfig: How to specify wildcard in alias?

Tags: linux, fonts, fontconfig

Noto family has a huge list of fonts. I want to make `Noto Serif *` the default families for serif fonts. Something like:

```
<fontconfig>
    <alias>
        <family>serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Noto Serif *</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
<fontconfig>
```

Comment: @Destroy666 Fixed, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is currently impossible - `<family>` element is documented to contain only one element:

> **`<family>`** 
> Holds a single font family name

while `<alias>` has to contain `<family>` and optionally can have `<prefer>`/`<accept>`/`<default>`:

> **`<alias>`** 
> Alias elements provide a shorthand notation for the set of common match operations needed to substitute one font family for another. They contain a `<family>` element followed by optional `<prefer>`, `<accept>` and `<default>` elements. Fonts matching the `<family>` element are edited to prepend the list of `<prefer>`ed families before the matching `<family>`, append the able families after the matching `<family>` and append the `<default>` families to the end of the family list.

and lastly the definition for the optional elements:

> **`<prefer>`, `<accept>`, `<default>`** 
> These hold a list of `<family>` elements to be used by the `<alias>` element.

[Source](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html)

So you have to define multiple family names instead.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like I need to write a generator script then. This should have been something built-in.